# The limiting distribution of method of moments estimator.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_i\sim p(x,\mu)$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ where $p(x,\mu) = \frac12 (1+\mu x)$ for $-1<x<1$ and $-1<\mu<1$. I fund the method of moments estimator is $\bar \mu_n = 3 \bar X$ where $\bar X$ denotes the sample mean. Next, the exercise asks me to find its limiting distribution. I don't understand what is mean by  limiting distribution... does it mean
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \bar \mu_n
$$
If yes, how may I compute it?

Thank you!

Comment: @Walter Why?$\int_{-1}^1 p(x,\mu)=1$ always no matter the value of $\mu$.

Comment: $\overline{\mu}_n$ is a random variable. So it has a cumulative distribution function. How do these CDFs behave as $n$ grows? (There is an important theorem that you probably know that you can use to make this part of the question easy.)

Comment: The limiting distribution of $\bar\mu_n$ is a Dirac mass at $\mu$ (which is not Earth shattering, to say the least). Instead, you might be asked to find a normalization such that the limit is not degenerate, for example, to compute the limit in distribution of $$\sqrt{n}\cdot(\bar\mu_n-\mu).$$

Comment: @Ian oh yea the SLLN right? So I may have $\bar\mu_n\to 3\mu$ right?

Comment: @Did Thank you for your comment. I think I may know how to deal with those problems now!

Comment: @tankonetoone Careful: you've called the parameter $\mu$, but $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{2} x(1+\mu x) dx$ is not actually $\mu$.

Comment: @Ian oh sure. The integration is $\mu/3$ and hence $\mu_n$ should go to $\mu$ right?

Comment: @tankonetoone Which comment? On main or on the answer?

Comment: @Did for the comment you made above. I think I that is asymptotically normal and I have a theorem to tell me that it goes to $N(0,\Sigma)$ for some $\Sigma$ I need to compute.

Comment: Yep. I would compute var$(X_1)$ if I were you, just in case... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The limiting distribution is precisely $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bar \mu_n.$$  To see what it might be, we calculate the moment generating function of $\bar \mu_n$:  $$M_{\bar \mu_n}(t) = (M_X(3t/n))^n = \left(\int_{x=-1}^1 \frac{e^{3tx/n}(1+\mu x)}{2} \, dx \right)^n = \left(\frac{n}{(3t)^2}\left(3mt \cosh \frac{3t}{n} + (3t-mn) \sinh \frac{3t}{n}\right)\right)^n,$$ where upon taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we obtain $$M_{\bar \mu_\infty}(t) = e^{mt}.$$  This is a degenerate MGF; i.e., $\Pr[\bar \mu_\infty = m] = 1$.

Comment: Simpler: SLLN. (But see my comment on main.)